# Use GeoDataFrame as a osgeo.ogr DataSource

Tags: python, ogr, geopandas

I have read shapefile into a `GeoDataFrame` and did some modification to it:

```
import geopandas as gpd

# Read shapefile into geodataframe
geodf = gpd.read_file("shapefile.shp")

# Do some "pandas-like" modifications to shapefile
geodf = modify_geodf(geodf)
```

However, I would also like to apply some functionality of `osgeo.ogr` module on it:

```
from osgeo import ogr

# Read shapefile into ogr DataSource
ds=ogr.Open("shapefile.shp")

# Do some "gdal/ogr-like" modifications to shapefile
ds = modify_ds(ds)
```

**QUESTION:** Is there any way to use or convert an already in-memory shapefile, currently in a form of a GeoDataFrame, as an `osgeo.ogr.DataSource` directly?

The way I do it so far is to save GeoDataFrame to file with `to_file()` and then `osgeo.ogr.Open()` it again, but this seems kind of redundant to me.

Comment: Why do you need to use both approaches, rather than one of the two?

Comment: It's just the way how I solved some separate tasks. Some by using ogr, some by using geopandas. The latter I find much more familiar since it is close to pandas. Well, I gave it a shot, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can pass the GeoDataFrame into ogr.Open in GeoJson format which is supported OGR vector format. Hence, you don't need to save temporary file into a disk:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from osgeo import ogr

# Read file into GeoDataFrame
data = gpd.read_file("my_shapefile.shp")

# Pass the GeoDataFrame into ogr as GeoJson
shp = ogr.Open(data.to_json())

# Do your stuff with ogr ...
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: it did not worked in my case https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396995/using-geopandas-geodataframe-in-gdal-grid-for-spatial-interpolation-viz-idw-nea

Answer (score 3):

No. Only [formats supported by OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html) can be opened with `ogr.Open()`.